# How to exclude a site or domain from a Google search

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I'm trying to search for something on the web, say "cold mountain by charles frazier" (without the quotes) and all the results I'm getting are on [books.google.com](https://books.google.com), and they aren't helpful. So, I want to exclude results from Google Books when I search. Is there some Google-search syntax to search *outside* a particular domain?

**P.S.** I know there's the `-` operator to exclude results containing a particular keyword.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: Yeah maybe it's better for webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm out of flags. Otherwise I will flag it as off-topic too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search in specific domain with `site:` and you can exclude specific domain with `-site:`

Comment: would be good to be able to exclude certain sites permanently in the settings, so that you don't have to remember to apply the `-site` thing every time.